# Trying to move list elements around in my unordered list

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So basically I have a unordered list and I used css to display the list in a row using (display:inline). And im having the problem where I try to position one of the list elements to the opposite side of the page. It will act as one whole unit basically. How do I move these separately from each other? Thanks ahead of time! #save-my-code

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
 <li>
   <a href='#'id="port">Portfolio</a>
 </li>
<li>
  <a href='#'id="youtube">Youtube</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href='#'id="blog">Blog</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href='#'id="photo">Photography</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please provide any screenshot how do you want.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the class `pull-right` to pull your elements to the right side of the page.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="pull-right">
       <a href='#'id="port">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li class="pull-right">
      <a href='#'id="youtube">Youtube</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'id="blog">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'id="photo">Photography</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, use

```
.pull-right {
    float: right
}
```

if you're not using bootstrap.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @dbigpotAwesome! Thanks for the response. I accidentally exited out without saving so I have to retype a bunch of code. But that looks like it will work. Didnt think of putting the class in my css and floating it right. Would it work if I tagged the ID instead?

Comment: As long as you're floating the `<li>` to the right and the `<ul>` element spans across the screen, it should work.

Comment: So I cant seem to get it to work. If im using bootstrap (cause I am) is there an other option? Thanks again for the response

Comment: Have a look at this - https://jsfiddle.net/x9xxpej0/ and see if you can figure it out. Else share yours, if possible, so we can see what's going on :)

Comment: Thanks man I actually just figured it out. Took a little more reading but heres my code.

Comment: So for some reasons I cant post my code. But basically I turned the nav-pills into navbar and then I margined my photography element to the left 500px. Worked perfectly for some reason. Oh I also moved the ul to the right 100px. Sorry for the bad explanation lol